# Why is my list not updating despite appending to the list?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a bit of a problem with my code below. After calling the command, the list does not update (it doesn't append the discord id of the user I mentioned to the list.) Even though in the print statement that I added after the code executes SHOWS the user's id in the list, but it's not.

```
cool_people = []
allowed_people = [1232332423472348]
@client.command()
async def makeCool(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    for allowed in allowed_people:
        if int(ctx.author.id) == allowed:
            print("hey u are allowed to use this command! good job")
            for coolUser in cool_people:
                if coolUser == member.id:
                    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} you are already cool!')
                elif coolUser != member.id:
                    print(member.id)
                    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been added")
                    cool_people.append(member.id)
                    print(cool_people)
```

Comment: you should not update an enumerate while enumerating it

Comment: `for coolUser in cool_people` the variable `cool_people` is an empty list so your if, elif statements never execute.

Comment: @gsb22 huh? What do you mean an "enumerate"?

Comment: also, where are `cool_people` getting value from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `in` instead of looping the entire list. In addition make the list global one method is using `client.XXXX`

```py
# Made it global
client.cool_people = []
client.allowed_people = [1232332423472348]

@client.command()
async def makeCool(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    # skip users not in allowed_people
    if ctx.author.id not in client.allowed_people:
        return await ctx.send("You are not allowed to use this")
    
    # add user to list if not in cool_pepole
    if member.id not in client.cool_people:
        client.cool_people.append(member.id)

    # code here
```